# Accessing a dictionary in the add method from the creator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have to implement a class called `Marathon`. In the creator a have to declare a dictionary with key 'runner' and value 'time'. I declare the dictionary in the creator. Then when I try to use that dictionary in the register method an error appear `NameError: name 'my_marathon' is not defined`. Can someone tell me how I access to that dictionary from my register method?

```
class Marathon:

    def __init__(self):
        """Set up this marathon without any runners."""
        my_marathon = {'runner', 'time'}


    def register(self, runner):
        """Register the runner. Return nothing."""

        my_marathon['runner'] = runner
```

Comment: As written, you can't - it's a local in `__init__`, it gets dereferenced as soon as the method ends. You should read up on basic Python OOP - what you want is an *attribute*. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes

Answer (score 0):

```
class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = -1

    def set_time(self, time):
        self.time = time


class Marathon:

    def __init__(self):
        """Set up this marathon without any runners."""
        self.runners = []


    def register(self, runner):
        """Register the runner. Return nothing."""

        self.runners.append(runner)
```

Use `self` to reference instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've fixed that but now another error appears: 
                                                                                             
   AttributeError: 'Marathon' object has no attribute 'my_marathon'

Comment: Edited my answer to something that may help you out.